# Запись CD, порядок файлов в ФС

Tags: linux, файловая-система, cd

Нужно записать диск с mp3 так, чтобы файлы в файловой системе располагались по-алфавиту. Для компьютера это, конечно безразлично, так как сортировка происходит автоматически, но при проигрывании диска на магнитоле и тому подобных устройствах композиции будут проигрываться согласно расположению в ФС.

Писал из-под линукса k3b файлы располагались хаотично (проверка ls -U)
Также писал xburn. Расположение фалов было отличное от диска, записанного k3b, но также не в нужном порядке.

Какие есть способы, или какой софт можно использовать, чтобы добиться нужного мне расположения файлов? Желательно ОС линукс, но можно и Windows.

Comment: еще может быть, что ПО на оконечном устройстве смотрит в `id3`-теги, а в тегах может быть что-то другое.

Comment: Нет, тег соответствует названию файла.

Answer (score 1):

в Brasero, после того, как вы добавите все файлы для записи, вы можете изменить порядок их записи на диск, просто перетаскивая их мышкой

Comment: Не заметил я такой возможности.

Comment: можно менять порядок mp3-файлов, только если создавать звуковой диск, для диска с данными порядок следования файлов изменять нельзя

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте записать ISO-образ. В `k3b`, например, такая возможность есть.

Добавьте файлы в проект, из проекта сделайте образ, проверьте расположение файлов в образе. А потом запишите образ. По крайней мере, образ записывается как единый файл, `k3b` в него не "залезет".

Comment: Теперь остается "заставить" программу запихать файлы в образ в нужном порядке.

Comment: я у себя попробовал добавить файлы в проект в k3b, добавляются в алфавитном порядке, как и надо.

Comment: Но на диск пишет в случайном.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor вы попробовали сначала сделать/записать в файл образ, потом его записать на диск, и всё равно то же самое?

Comment: Попробую. Я уже думал об этом.